# A180 diesel doesn't start, pops open diesel cap instead

Tags: engine, starting, diesel, mercedes-benz

When I try to start my diesel Mercedes A180 it doesn't start and the diesel cap opens instead!

When I turn the key, sometimes it makes the starting noise (but then stops). At other times it doesn't even make the noise when I turn the key and other time didn't even light up any light on the panel. And as I said, when I turn the key, the fuel cap opens.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Could it be the battery?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't start", can you be more specific - Does it turn but not fire? Does it make any noises? Or does it do nothing at all?

Comment: Sometimes it makes the starting noise but then stops and the diesel cap opens.other times doesn't even make the noise.and one time the lights in the panel didn't even light up.

Comment: What do you mean my making the noise? What noise, does the engine turn over?

Comment: So you mean the fuel filler door pops open or the actual screw on cap somehow pops off?  Is there normally a pushbutton to open the filler door, because if so this sounds like a bad electrical issue.